# Codeigniter route

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, routes

I have this url
`http://mysite.local/awesome-shirts.html`

I want to route it to

`http://mysite.local/category/shirts/awesome-shirts.html`

The third segment of the url is dynamic.

Does anyone knows how to do this one? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps you .

```
$route['category/(:*)/(:*)'] = "/$1";
```